# A question on connected component

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose:

- $B_i \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, $0\le w_i\in \mathbb{R}$ $(i = 0,1,2,\ldots,m)$, and $w_o>0$.
- ${\rm P}(x) ={\rm{B}_m} x ^m + \cdots + B_1 x  + A_0$ is a matrix polynomial,  where $x $ is a complex variable.
- ${\rm q}(x) =\rm{w}_m x^m + \cdots +w_1 x + w_0$
- $U= \left\{ {x  \in \mathbb{C}:\left\| P(x)^{-1} \right\| \ge (\varepsilon q(|x|))}^{-1} \right\}$, where $\left\| \cdot \right\|$ is any subordinate matrix norm.

Why does every connected component of $U$ have nonempty
interior?(For all $\varepsilon >0$)